# Posting to facebook wall using graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a text with image to facebook wall using graph api.

I'm using following code snippet for this.

```
 var body = {
      message : 'this is a test message',
      image : 'http://someurltoimage.png'
 };

 FB.api(
        "/me/feed",
        "POST",
        {
            "object": {
                "message": body.message,
                "picture": body.image
            }
        },
        function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
              //process when success
          }
        }
    );
```

But I'm getting following error code.

```
 error: Object
 code: 100
 error_subcode: 1349125
 message: "Invalid parameter"
 type: "FacebookApiException"
```

There's no document for this error.

Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: read how to upload photo. after photo uploaded your feed will update and people will see your upload. don't post to /feed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"I'm trying to post a text with image to facebook wall using graph api."*

- You are **using `/feed`**, to upload a photo you have to **use `/photos` call**
- You are sending an invalid parameter `object` which contains your parameters, to Facebook, the API doesn't know that your parameter `Object` is an `object` (I know, too many `object`s here, in another way, you're sending an object within an object

To solve all this, replace `me/feed` with `me/photos` and the 3rd argument (your object) with the `body`

```
 var body = {
      message : 'this is a test message',
      url: 'http://someurltoimage.png'
 };

 FB.api("/me/photos",
        "POST",
        body,
        function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
              //process when success
          }
        }
 );
```

Comment: hello Adam, it return me "(#324) Requires upload file"